# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character error unexpected token <

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

i have a html button with "button-account" name  in html body and want update aspx page with ajax when user click the button

I get this error in google chrom

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

and this in fire fox

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Here's my Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#button-account").bind("click", "accountRegister");

        function accountRegister() {
            var waitObj = "<span class='wait' > <img  src='Resource/Images/loading.gif' alt='' /> </span>";
            var user = $("[name='username']").val();
            var pass = $("[name='password']").val();
            var dataObj = {
                "username": user,
                "password": pass,
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Checkout.aspx/login",
                data: dataObj,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                beforSend: function () {
                    $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
                    $(this).after(waitObj);
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                    alert("success");
                    $("#checkout").slideUp("slow");
                    $("#payment-address").slideDown("slow");
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert("error");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $(this).attr("disabled", "false");
                    $(".wait").remove();
                },
            });
        }


    });





</script>
```

and here's my webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string login()
    {
        //bool UserIsValid = false;
        //string userName = "";
        //string pass = "";
        //MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(userName);
        //pass = u.GetPassword();
        //if (UserIsValid)
        //{
        //  //  returnAsHtml = "true";

        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    //returnAsHtml = "use is not valid";

        //}
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string result = js.Serialize("{ a:'1' }");
        return result;

    }
```

and fiddler return 200 status.
**but return html**. i know this is my mistake. how solve it?

any help is appriciate...

Comment: Could you show the part of the code, where `JSON.parse()` is called?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so sorry!!!

in other section a called this

```
 $('#button-login').live('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Checkout.aspx?login',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#checkout #login :input'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#button-login').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#button-login').after('<span class="wait">&nbsp;<img src="Resource/Images/loading.gif" alt="" /></span>');
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#button-login').attr('disabled', false);
            $('.wait').remove();
        },
        success: function (json) {
            $('.warning, .error').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            } else if (json['error']) {
                $('#checkout .checkout-content').prepend('<div class="warning" style="display: none;">' + json['error']['warning'] + '</div>');

                $('.warning').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The server probably returns an error-page (e.g. `"<html> ..."`) instead of the JSON response you expected.

Use [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), chrome's developer tools or a similar tool to check what the exact answer is, that the server returns.

---

In response to your comments:

Check what the content of the returned HTML page is. It's probably an error caused by your server-side code (e.g. an unhandled exception) or the server-side configuration.

Comment: hi, fiddler result is 200, ajax run successfully

Comment: @Edalat: but what is the content of the response? Is it the expected JSON or is it an HTML (error-)page?

Comment: it return html, unfourtunetly.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
var dataObj = {
                "username": user,
                "password": pass,
            };
```

To this

```
var dataObj = {
                "username": user,
                "password": pass
            };
```

You have an extra comma `,` (`"password": pass,`) after pass, so it is not able to serialize it properly.

**Edit:**

Try this

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string login()
    {
        //bool UserIsValid = false;
        //string userName = "";
        //string pass = "";
        //MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(userName);
        //pass = u.GetPassword();
        //if (UserIsValid)
        //{
        //  //  returnAsHtml = "true";

        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    //returnAsHtml = "use is not valid";

        //}

        //JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        //string result = js.Serialize("{ a:'1' }"); // no need to serialize 
        return "{ a:'1' }";

    }
```